# Wildcard routes with Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I'm trying to match a Vue.js route like so:

```
{
  path: '/#/reset*',
  name: 'Confirm Reset Password',
  meta: { title: `Confirm password reset` },
  component: ConfirmResetPassword
},
```

to a URL that looks like this

```
mywebsite.com/#/reset-password
```

but it's not working- it just goes to the home page for some reason. Am I doing the wildcard wrong or is the '#' in a reserved namespace?

I also have these two routes:

```
{
  path: '/',
  name: 'Home',
  component: Home
},
{
  path: '*',
  name: '404',
  meta: { title: `Page not found` },
  component: Error404
}
```

**Edit

I have history mode on and the URL is generated from a Django back-end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/#` shouldn't be a part of the `path`. Use like below:

```
{
  path: '/reset*',
  name: 'Confirm Reset Password',
  meta: { title: `Confirm password reset` },
  component: ConfirmResetPassword
},
```

The fact that you have `/#` in your URLs is because you don't have History mode on (which is not a problem, it is just a different way of using vue-router). So you declare your paths without `/#`.

Comment: Thanks @acdcjunior but the '#' comes from a Django generated path so I have to match against it.

Comment: If I do it anyway like how you suggested it doesn't work

Comment: I do have history mode on - does this mean it's impossible to match against?

Answer (score -1):

If history mode is on I can't match against a URL provided pre-fixed with '#' - solution is to change the URL being generated on the back-end.