# How can I handle all vue js routes start with "/admin" or "/user"

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-component, vuex

In Laravel we write below:

```
Route::prefix('/user')->name('User')->group(function()
{
// Our Routes
});
```

in Vue Js, when I searched I couldn't find anything.
please if someone knows about it, tell me is it possible for Vue js?
or All time we should add /admin or /user in all routes of Vue js!

Comment: You could use nested routes. Doc: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html

Comment: Probably dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49969436/wildcard-routes-with-vue-js